# Laravel \Request::get()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to check if any GET variables exist? I'm not trying to find a particular GET variable I need to create an if statement if ANY get variable exists.

For example, I have a route

> /product

If for any reason someone adds variables to the end of the route I'd like to include a canonical link in the header of the page.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ url($page->slug) }}" />
```

I can apply this canonical link if I know the parameter. For example if some one adds

> /product?model=1

However if someone adds a get variable I'm unaware of then this wouldn't include the link.

I've tried

```
@if(/Request::get())
   <link rel="canonical" href="{{ url($page->slug) }}" />
@endif
```

However this squawks with

> Too few arguments to function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\Request::query()` to get url params in laravel blade

Try to check all params with this

```
<?php print_r(\Request::query()); ?>
```

And apply this code to check any param exist in url

```
@if(\Request::query())
```

Check details in [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#request-path-and-method)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about \Request::query(); I got this working before your answer with $_GET. I'm guessing they do the same thing. I'll use your suggestion as I prefer to keep it in line with Laravel :P

Comment: Then you should select this answer as the one that worked for you.

Comment: Be aware that `While the input method retrieves values from entire request payload (including the query string), the query method will only retrieve values from the query string:` - [ref: Laravel docs] This means you cannot rely on `query()` when dealing with values not in query string e.g from POST request.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin : You are right, But he wants only from `$_GET` not from `$_POST` check [his previous method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48112368/2815635)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by counting **$_GET**. for example:

```
@if(count($_GET) > 0)
    <link rel="canonical" href="{{ Request::url() }}" />
@endif
```

Comment: Home come? this is the only method I can see working so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check url contains params or not, then you can use this-

```
if($request->input()){
   ///do your task
}
```

And in blade check like-

```
@if(\Request::input())

@endif
```

or if you want to get all keys then use $key => $value notation in [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
$keys = array();
foreach ($request->input()  as $key => $part) {
   $keys[] = $key;
}
```

**$keys** will contain all parameter or input field

Comment: This doesn't fit with the question asked unfortunately. I asked if there was a way to check if any exist. For a streamlined answer simply count(\Request::query()) is all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just get all the $_GET variables through `Input::get()`:

```
$parameters= \Input::get()
```

Comment: As of 5.2 Input was replaced with Request. And you can't call get() on Request on it's own.